# Marriage separation rule in Hinduism?

Tags: marriage

Is there any rule of separation after marriage in Hinduism? Might be the case both (husband and wife) thinking is totally different, so they fight every day and they feel they cannot live together. Then what is the way to get rid  of this situation?

Is there any rule in any Hindu religious book?

Comment: Might be duplicate but I could not found answer, in India there are many Murder case in Hindu family because they cannot separate religiously. I try to understand the religion but could not found any proof, that's why I posted this question here but still no answer.

Comment: See http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Divorce Generally, 'they fight every day' is not reason enough for separation in Hinduism. In old times, there used to be child marriage where the girl used to stay with husband and in-laws from a young age, so there was a good chance to adjust and avoid "fight every day" and "feel they cannot live together". At some point people lost sight of reason behind this tradition and this 'child marriage' turned into a business with parents of young girls selling them to aging men for a quick buck. From that...

Comment: ...we now jumped to other extreme where both wife and husband are working and want to stay independent even after marriage. What do you expect? This problem is not limited to today's Hinduism or India alone.

Comment: Mr. SV and Krishna thanks for your comment but I don't want the static, I want the shloka, from vedas, upanishada, that, is there any way or not. Rest static, percentage, leaving separately is not the religious things.

Comment: What do you mean by 'static'?

Comment: See [Manu 9-101](https://archive.org/stream/lawsofman00manu#page/n487/mode/2up) ('Let mutual fidelity continue until death,' this may be considered as the summary of the highest law for husband and wife.) and 9-102 (Let man and woman, unite in marriage, constantly exert themselves, that (they may not be) disunited (and) may not violate their mutual fidelity.) Also see http://www.hinduism.co.za/marriage.htm#Re-marriage

Comment: Mr. SV see your comments: 1.fight every day' is not reason enough for separation, 2. we both wife and husband are working and want to stay independent even after marriage. 3. Be faith full to your partner entire life. What about Krishna (more than 10000 wifes), Raja Dasrath (father of Ram) more than1000 wifes, they were not religious ? Give me if you have any evidence from bool(vedas, puranas) please

Comment: What has Krishna's or Dasaratha's wives got anything to do with divorce or separation? I already gave you links to [Manu-smriti](https://archive.org/details/lawsofman00manu) (it's a Hindu scripture) -- what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Also, see http://www.kamakoti.org/newlayout/template/hindudharma.html/18/1/hindu/Marriage (Hindu Dharma: Marriage) and http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part18/chap17.htm (Ideals of Marriage)